# Is it possible to have a Java program communicate with terminal?

Tags: java, linux, terminal

I know you can use terminal/cmd to pass in arguments to a Java program, but can you do it the other way, ie have a Java program pass info back to terminal?

More specfically I want to do something like this:

- use terminal to launch and pass in value to a Java program
- do stuff based on input and pass back a value
- use that value to encrypt a file using terminal
- repeat

Comment: System.in? Scanner? Read the input?

Comment: If you want to write a [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface), you can use [JCurses](https://github.com/sunhong/jcurses).

Comment: No, I want my Java file to pass info back to terminal, not the other way around.

Comment: Why am I getting docked down for this question?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But isnt a TUI using to pass input from terminal to the Java program and not the other way around?

Comment: A User Interface requires input and output.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch True. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of a program written in any language that does what you're wondering whether Java can do?

Answer (score 0):

To get your started:

> Every Java application has a single instance of class Runtime that allows the application to interface with the environment in which the application is running. The current runtime can be obtained from the getRuntime method. - Java API

You can basically run anything in terminal using this class:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null);
```

Where command is like `ffmpeg -help`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The sort of equivalent of args passed to program in the start of main method is an Integer passed to program exit statement, being the return value of the program:

```
System.exit(0);
```

This number can be any Integer.

If you run your program by java yourProgram, you can get exit code by

```
echo $?
```